# Django- order by a field unless it is null, then use another

Tags: django

Lets say I have the following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_1 = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_2 = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Each model will have at least 1 of the date fields.  What I want to do is order by the following- if the model has `date_1`, order it by `date_1`.  If it does not have `date_1`, instead order it by `date_2`.  Doing something like this:

```
MyModel.objects.all().order_by('date_1', 'date_2')
```

will stick all of the null date_1 values to the end.  Whereas I would like to have the "interleaved".  For example, I would want the following output (in json format):

```
[
   {"id": 1, "date_1": "2020-02-01", "date_2": null},
   {"id": 4, "date_1": null, "date_2": 2020-02-02},           # orders by date_2 as there is no date_1
   {"id": 2, "date_1": "2020-02-03", "date_2": "2020-02-01"}, # orders by date_1, ignores date_2
   {"id": 3, "date_1": "2020-02-04", "date_2": null},
]
```

Is this possible to do with the django ORM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make an annotation with a [**`Coalesce`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce), and then order on that field:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    date=Coalesce('date1', 'date2')
).order_by('date')
```

or even shorter: you can order by the `Coalesce` directly:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

MyModel.objects.order_by(Coalesce('date1', 'date2').asc())
```